# Can I create a link to open the document properties pane from an email?

Tags: list-form, powerapps-forms, modern-document-library

Using JSON Formatting, I have created a button in my document library with a customRowAction of `editProps`. Is it possible to create a hyperlink that I can send in an email that will provide this same behaviour?

I have tried using https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Library/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=x which opens the form but doesn't show the files in the library. I would like to open the library with a file selected and the EditForm visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use filters in your url (make any metadata to link the file)
the example with ID field, url looks like:

../Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=1&FilterType1=Counter&viewid=ea91960d-d90b-4da0-bd87-fa74721511b5